# MySQL slave stuck at 'System lock'

Tags: replication, mariadb, master-slave

We have Master-Slave replication but since +1h none changes are replicated because slave is stuck on 'System lock':

```
(dh@DB02) [(none)]> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: XXXXXXXXXXX
                  Master_User: XXXXXXXXXXX
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 10
              Master_Log_File: XXXXXXXX-VM011-bin.008576
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 779580207
               Relay_Log_File: DB-02-relay-bin.000494
                Relay_Log_Pos: 377550713
        Relay_Master_Log_File: XXXXXXXX-VM011-bin.008576
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 508746847
              Relay_Log_Space: 977983642
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 4998
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: System lock
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have checked event on Master server and it is:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show binlog events in 'XXXXXXXX-VM011-bin.008576' from 508746847 limit 1;
+---------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+
| Log_name                  | Pos       | Event_type | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                      |
+---------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+
| XXXXXXXX-VM011-bin.008576 | 508746847 | Gtid       |         1 |   508746889 | BEGIN GTID 0-1-6324465194 |
+---------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Slave:

- Server version: 5.5.5-10.2.13-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
- Process list query shows only sleeping queries.

I don't see any load on replication server.
Can any one help me what to do?

Comment: Looks like a bug. You could try `stop slave; start slave` and see if it recovers. 10.2 /10.3 are out of maintenance so consider upgrading to a new LTS version (like 10.11)

Comment: I wasn't able to stop slave. We had to stop server by kill -9. When we got error on system lock server on one file.

Answer (score 0):

The "System lock" occurs while a transaction is in the process of acquiring the locks on tables on which it operates.

The way this is stuck is obviously a deadlock. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` or `SHOW PROCESSLIST` might show the other thread involved in the deadlock.

You can search [JIRA](https://jira.mariadb.org/) for similar bug reports, to see if its fixed, but there's a lot. There's a reasonable chance the [latest 10.2 release](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-102-series/) or an actual supported MariaDB release will fix this processing error.